# CSS - Position Absolute Not Going to Bottom

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">

<h2 class="title">Title Goes Here</h2>

</div>
```

with this css:

```
.container {

 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;

}

h2.title {

width: 100%;
background: red;
color: white;
bottom: 0;

}
```

But the h2 is not appearing at the bottom.  What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/phnezq25/2/

Answer (score 1):

you forgot `position: absolute` on `<h2>`.
Also remember to remove its default margin, otherwise the element won't stay exactly on the bottom

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/phnezq25/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your h2 style

```
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/phnezq25/4/